# How to get all items, their unit prices, shipping costs and all other related costs to an order id?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Webpay for the payment method, and it requires to list the items, unit prices, total price, shipping costs, and all involved costs similar to the cart in a success page at the end of the purchase.

I'm using these lines to get the last Order ID, but also need to get what I describe above. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order
        ->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do that.

Just open this controller `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` and find the lines, where all the checkout session variables are being `unset`. Before they are unset, assign them again to the template variables (`$this->data['order'] = $this->session->data['order'];`, etc.)

Now You can modify Your success template and use these data as usual.